# Warning comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, null-terminated

I am getting a warning when I iterate through the character pointer and check when the pointer reaches the null terminator.

```
 const char* message = "hi";

 //I then loop through the message and I get an error in the below if statement.

 if (*message == "\0") {
  ...//do something
 }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'char *')
```

I thought that the `*` in front of `message` dereferences message, so I get the value of where message points to? I do not want to use the library function `strcmp` by the way.

Comment: Note that `"\0"` is a string with two consecutive null bytes (so the second can't be found by string manipulating functions such as `strlen()` because they stop at the first null byte).  The empty string `""` consists of a single null byte.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It should be

```
if (*message == '\0')
```

In C, simple quotes delimit a single character whereas double quotes are for strings.

Comment: Oh, so the double quotes make the difference? Thanks I'm able to compile successfully now.

Comment: I'm happy to help. The warning means that you are trying to compare a character with a string, hence the "comparison between pointer (string) and integer (character)" message.

Answer (score 10):

This: `"\0"` is a string, not a character.  A character uses single quotes, like `'\0'`.

Answer (score 8):

In this line ...

```
if (*message == "\0") {
```

... as you can see in the warning ...

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'char *')
```

... you are actually comparing an `int` with a `char *`, or more specifically, an `int` with an address to a `char`.

To fix this, use one of the following:

```
if(*message == '\0') ...
if(message[0] == '\0') ...
if(!*message) ...
```

On a side note, if you'd like to compare strings you should use `strcmp` or `strncmp`, found in `string.h`.